# Admin validation system PHP and mysqli (procedural)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
function activate($con, $email){
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);
    return mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = '".$email."'");
}

if($role == 'Administrator'){
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `active` = 0");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $email = $row['email'];
                $name = $row['name'];
                $surname = $row['surname'];
                echo $name . ' ' . $surname . ' - ' . $email . '<form method="post"><input type="submit" name="activate" value="Activeaza"></form></br>';
                if(isset($_POST['activate']))
                activate($con, $email);
            }           
        }

    }
```

This is my code. I want to make a validation page for admin from where he can validate the users. Using this code when I activate a user it activates all the users. I don't know how to exit that while with variables one by one. Thanks up, i'm beginner in php :D

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need to exit that while, but you are doing too much things on that while loop

since you didnt specify the action on your form, the form must submit to the page itself when submitted. you can separate it.

so you can add this in your form:

```
echo $name . ' ' . $surname . ' - ' . $email . '<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="activate" value="Activeaza">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value=\"'. $email . \"'>
</form></br>';
```

And add this at the top of your code:

```
if ( $SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )
{
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     activate($con,$email);
}
```

hope this helps
to know more about hidden input type see this link:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.hidden.html

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a form per user create 1 form and input all users into the form with the while loop and give each user a distinct identifier such as user ids.

You could use HTML select or give each user a row with a check box

Then put your code outside of the form.

```
if(isset($_POST['activate']))    
activate($con, $email);
```

If you use the check box method you can activate multiple users at once with a modified activate function